# Can you only pray fard prayer on time without praying sunnah muakkadah before or after it

Tags: salat, practical-islam

I work 9-6 office job which is currently approx 80 kms away which needs daily commuting and on that also chances are I might get late sometimes and currently I pray fajr and Isha and the rest 3 qadha prayer after arriving at Home By the will of Allah, But my concern is how should I do that on prescribed time.